# Add a new key to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm on a Mac now and previously I was able to set up and access an EC2 instance successfully from Windows XP. I want to create a new key for access from Mac, used the console management screen to generate a new key, saved the PEM file, changed permission on the file to owner RW only and then tried ssh but couldn't get it to work. Here's my command

```
ssh -v -i .ssh/ec2-mac.pem ec2-user@ec2-204-236-143-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Here's the verbose output

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-204-236-143-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com http://204.236.143.254 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/ec2-mac.pem type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-204-236-143-254.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/bob/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/ec2-mac.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Anyone know what I'm missing? Oh and I am able to ssh into a different instance with the original key created for that instance making this even more puzzling.

Permissions are set correctly using chmod 600. The one thing I'm not sure is in the control panel management screen when I list Instances, it only shows the original value in "Key Pair Name" column, should it show both?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create new key for new operating system. You can make use of your old Windows XP key in MAC. 
Another point is when you launch an instance with a private key, then you can only login through that key only. A new key won't help.

Regards,
Sanket Dangi

Comment: I didn't have access to the Windows machine at that time, so I figure I'll create a new one. I'm using the Windows key now and it works. Isn't there a way to add a new public key to the instance after launch? I know I can use ssh to add a new key but I would need access to the new public key which AWS didn't provide me.

Comment: No, there is no way to create a public key to the instance after launch.Only way to have another key is to use ssh from the instance and generate another key.